# bootstrap set margin left equal to .container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a problem with Bootstrap. I want to set two elements - one with content which is centered (lets name it `.top`) and another which will be equally on the left side to `.top` and on the right side it'll stick to the right side of the browser (lets name it `.btm`).
I know that when i'll add `.container` class it will center my `.top` element (by adding `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`), but how to make the `.btm` element to be on the same level as `.top` element on the left side? When i'll set some `margin-left` i'll lose the value of it in first changing the width of browser. How can i achieve this?
Currently i have something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="top">
      <strong>top text</strong>, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </div>a
</div>


<div class="row"> 
  <div class="btm"> <!-- i want to make this equal on the left side as the ".top" element-->
    <strong>bottom text</strong>, , lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
}
.top{
    height: 100px;
}
.btm{
  margin-left: 10%;
  background: #008B4F;
}
```

Here's the codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGdmQG

Comment: What i was looking was:
    `<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                <div class="top">
                    <strong>top text</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <div class="btm">
                    <strong>bottom text</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`

Answer (score 2):

You Should Close **`<div class="container">`** at last after to the .btm section.

What you did is you have closed the div immediatly after the ".top" section.

And remove margin-left:10% on your .btm css.

Your HTML Should Be:-

```
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="top">
            <strong>top text</strong>, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, 
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row"> 
          <div class="btm"> <!-- i want to make this equal on the left side as the ".top" element-->
           <strong>bottom text</strong> lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsumipsum
          </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:-

```
.btm{
  background: #008B4F;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go my friend

```css
body {
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
}
.top{
    height: 100px;
}
.btm{
  background: #008B4F;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="top">
      <strong>top text</strong>, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row"> 
  <div class="btm">
    <strong>bottom text</strong>, , lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin left from btm class

```
   .btm{
      background: #008B4F;
    }
```